# How might a user configure which video is shown on page without editing the page?

Tags: panels

A Drupal 7 site has an embedded YouTube video on the home page. It is not always displayed. Sometimes the video being displayed is changed. The home page is arranged by a Page Manager Variant, and the container with the video is "Custom Content". When someone wants to hide/show the video or change the link, they have to ask me because the Page Manager can only be accessed by an administrator. I want to give certain users the ability to show/hide the video and change the video to which it links, but without changing other content on the home page or modifying the layout of the site.

I don't really know what I'm doing when it comes to Drupal, and I'm having trouble figuring out the right things to search for to accomplish this.

I want the appropriate users to be able to choose which YouTube video is embedded and whether it is shown. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: My opinion: Custom module, new permission "edit front page video", new admin settings form only accessible to roles with the new permission, form with textfield to paste the video link, save it into a variable, then programmatically build the YouTube markup from that variable value (the link, with fallback maybe) and either preprocess the resulting markup into the page or have a custom block placed at the right place to render it.

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1

1. Create a content type: e.g. "Home Page Video".
2. Add fields: YouTube, text area, image, etc. Basically all the fields you would want to structure that "section" on the home page.
3. Give permissions for the fields with field permissions (additional security measure, you'll see why later)

### Step 2

1. Create a few nodes for "Home Page Video"
2. Set your view modes

### Step 3

1. Create a View to show only "Home Page Video" content.
2. Choose Bootstrap Grid (Views Bootstrap module and Bootstrap Field
   Group module) and add fields
   OR
   Choose unformatted list: Rendered
   entity and a View Mode
3. Set a filter: "promoted to front page"
4. Set a Pager: Display a specified number of items and choose 1, More
   link: no
5. Set a sort criteria: "Content: Updated date" (The date the content
   was last updated.) and set it to "descending"
6. Create a pane view from this view.
7. Save

### Step 4

1. Enable: `System - page_manager - node_edit - Node add/edit form -
   /node/%node/edit`
2. Create a new variant of node_edit template in Page Manager
3. Selection rule: Node being edited is bundle "Home Page Video"
4. Selection rule: Logged in user has one of "my user role"
5. Content: Add the form fields you want this user to edit AND add the
   base form (General Form) in order to get the submit button. If you
   have set certain fields to be required on your Home Page Video
   content type, they will show in the base form UNLESS you add them in
   through the cog wheel "Add content" and choose FORM and then choose
   the specific form field that is required. Like that you have the
   ability to choose where that field goes in your edit form layout.
   More control.
6. Save

### Step 5

1. Add your pane view of "Home Page Video" to your Home Page Page Variant at the position where you want it to show up on your Home Page.
2. In order for your pane view to show up, you might have to clear the cache. If you use Drush, simply type: drush cc all
3. Go look again for that pane view and add it.
4. Save

Et voilá.
No need for a custom module. Permissions are dealt with by the 'selection rules' in your node_edit page variant.